# Cannot access default value in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am drawing a triangle with "#" as default value if 'char' is not defined.
When I define 'char' I get the triangle drawn with that particular value.

If 'char' is defined then triangle must be drawn in characters from 'char' else it should use default value '#'.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

```js
function triangle(size, char = 0) {

  if (typeof char === 'undefined') {
    let hashKey = "#"
    while (hashKey.length <= size) {
      console.log(hashKey);
      hashKey += "#";
    }
  } else {
    let hashKey = char
    while (hashKey.length <= size) {
      console.log(hashKey);
      hashKey += char;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: With your default initialiser `= 0` on the parameter declaration, `char` will *never* be undefined.

Comment: `char` is never `undefined`. Whenever it gets that value (either by omitting it in the call or explicitly passing `undefined`), it is automatically assigned the default value `0`. So the first branch of your `if` will never be true.

Comment: Yes I saw this, thanks, but how else to make it an optional value?

Comment: Use `char = '#'` instead of `char = 0`

Comment: just don't assign a default value  `function(triangle, char) { ... `  or set char to the desired value `function triangle (size, char = '#') { ...` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your default initialiser `= 0` on the parameter declaration, `char` will *never* be undefined.

You'll want to write

```
function triangle(size, char) {
    if (typeof char === 'undefined') {
        char = "#"
    }
    let hashKey = char;
    while (hashKey.length <= size) {
        console.log(hashKey);
        hashKey += char; 
    }
}
```

or

```
function triangle(size, char = '#') {
    let hashKey = char;
    while (hashKey.length <= size) {
        console.log(hashKey);
        hashKey += char; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a default value to `char` you can do that in the parameter defintion:

```js
function triangle (size, char = '#'){
  let hashKey = char
  while(hashKey.length <= size ){
    console.log(hashKey);
    hashKey += char; 
  }
}
triangle(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare 'char' in your parametr when you call a function.

Just make it like 'function triangle (size, char)' and change condition to 'if (!char)'.